# Find nearest bigger value for all elements of array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm looking for a fast algorithm (or any hints) to do this;

- Formally, for each element *a<sub>i</sub>* of an array, find the index *j* which

  - *j > i*
  - *a<sub>i</sub> < a<sub>j</sub>*
  - *j - i* is minimum

Here is a sample and *O(n^2)* implementation

```
    std::vector<double> v = { 3, 1.5, 4, 2, 5 };
    
    std::vector<int> out(v.size());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        out[i] = -1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < v.size(); j++)
        {
            if (v[j] > v[i])
            {
                out[i] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
            
    for (int i : out) std::cout << i << ' '; // => 2 2 4 4 -1
```

Comment: Unless you know that the array is sorted, I think `O(N^2)` is the best you can do?

Comment: I believe what you're trying to do is same as [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/)? [Modified implementation.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RHGS5RM6pc6krSOC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done easily using stack in O(n) time complexity by following the steps mentioned below:

**Step-1:**  Maintain a stack that could store indices.

**Step-2:** Iterate through the array and check the following condition:
**Condition:** If the element of the array at the index at top of the array is less than the element at the current index then the nearest bigger element for the index at the top is the current one.

**Step-3:** Push the current index to the stack.

**Example:
[8,4,2,5,9]**

dp = [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1] # Array to store the indexes

**Iteration-1:**

Element = 8

Stack = [] # Empty

Push 0 to stack (index of 8)

**Iteration-2:**

Element = 4

Stack = [0]

Push 1 to stack (index of 4)

**Iteration-3:**

Element = 2

Stack = [0,1]

Push 2 to stack (index of 2)

**Iteration-4:**

Element = 5

Stack = [0,1,2]

Pop from stack -> 2 element = 2

dp[2] = 3

Pop from the stack -> 1 element = 4

dp[1] = 3

Push 3 to stack (index of 5)

**Iteration-5:**

Element = 9

Stack = [0,3]

Pop from stack -> 3 element = 5

dp[3] = 4

Pop from the stack -> 0 element = 8

dp[0] = 4

Push 4 to stack (index of 9)

*Now your answer for array = [8 4 2 5 9] is stored in array **dp**:*

**[4,3,3,4,-1]**